# using subclipse with an existing source project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

My Eclipse (3.7.2) java project uses existing source that is in a separate directory on my drive from my project. 
IE:
My eclipse project folder is c:\eclipseProjects\myProject
The source code for that project lives in c:\java_source

My source directories are "sandbox" directories for Subversion, ie they already have .svn folders in them. I have already checked them out using a different SVN client.

I installed Subclipse, and connected it to my repository, but I can't seem to "link" it to my local working copy and have it see that a source file in my project corresponds to a file in the SVN repository.

I don't want to 'share project' and import my project into the SVN repo. I don't need my project under SVN control, just my source folders. And since my project folder doesn't contain a .svn folder, eclipse/subclipse doesn't seem to figure this out.

NOTE: The SVN client versions are the same (both 1.7). 
I have tried tricks like renaming my project and naming it back, restarting eclipse, etc.

Does anybody have any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of setup is not supported.  The root of your project in Eclipse has to be a working copy, and everything after that is discovered by calling SVN API's.  A SVN client looking at the root of your Eclipse project will have no knowledge of these others folders somewhere else on your hard drive.

Note that you do not have to store the Eclipse .project and .classpath files in version control, but the folder itself has to be linked to a repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems odd that it cannot see that I have a linked source folder, and that folder has a .svn folder in it, and go from there. Why does it have to be only from the project root? I'm asking that rhetorically mostly.. I believe what you are saying, its just frustrating.